# Remove carriage return and line feed from string in JSP using JSTL . Fetching string from SQL

Tags: java, sql, string, jsp, jstl

I have fetched string from db. The string coming from DB is like this:

```
 "Hello & B'yeeee-

Forest"
```

I have set this value in java bean and passed it to JSP. In JSP, the value is printing like and in page source also:

```
Hello & B'yeeee-

Forest
```

When i copied this string to notepad++ to see special characters in this , value was:

```
    Hello & B'yeeee- CL RF

    Forest
```

I want to remove this CL RF from string in JSP using JSTL tag . I have already tried

```
   jstl:replace
```

function().

Comment: Please post what you have tried with the `replace` function.

Comment: how did you try jstl:replace function?? did you try it as below ?     `<c:set var="newLine" value="\n"/>
   ${fn:replace(data, newLine, "; ")}`

Comment: I have tried below two conditions:

productTitle - contains string value. 

<c:set var="newline" value="<%= \"\n\" %>" />
${fn:replace(productTitle,newline,'')} 
and

${fn:replace(productTitle,"\\r\\n|\\r|\\n",'')} 

but none of them is working..